# Having issues submitting data to sql database on WordPress: function fires, data collected, $wpdb->insert seems to not work

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-database

I am so sorry. I have been looking at this code for like 2 hours and trying to figure out why it is not working. Function fires, correct data is gathered into the variables - somewhere after the $table variable and before $output - something goes wrong. In $data = array all values are correct - I just the spelling 10 times. Columns match to variables. The data just does not get sent to the database.  I have zero clue at this point - any help is appreciated. Thanks.

wp_send_json($output) works and fires value 2.

```
function form_obj_send(){

global $wpdb;

$output = ['status' => 1];
$first_name = sanitize_text_field($_POST["first_name"]);
$last_name = sanitize_text_field($_POST["last_name"]);
$email = sanitize_text_field($_POST["email"]);
$subject = sanitize_text_field($_POST["subject"]);
$message = sanitize_text_field($_POST["message"]);

$table = $wpdb->prefix . 'formuserinput';
$data = array(
    'first_name' => $first_name,
    'last_name' => $last_name,
    'email' => $email,
    'subject' => $subject,
    'message' => $message
);

$wpdb->insert($table, $data);

$output['status'] = 2;
wp_send_json($output);
```

}

(EDIT): After some sleep - the code is working perfectly - I was looking at the wrong information in MySQL...lets forget this ever happened, LOL. The lesson for the day? Facing an unsolvable problem? - Get some sleep. =)

Comment: I had an issue before where the column I was inserting to was a varchar with max length and one of my variables was too long and it failed without an error, I would suggest you check the max length `message` column can be.

Comment: Thanks, Josh - after some sleep...the code was working the whole time...when looking at the SQL database, I was looking at 'Show structure', instead of 'Select Data'... let's not talk about this again...LOL. Thanks for your help. =)